# Markdown Editors that support sequence diagrams

Tags: markdown, message-sequence-chart

I'm looking for a Markdown editor that satisfies the following conditions:

1. Supports sequence diagrams (ideally PlantUML).
2. Has some kind of off-line editor with live preview of the diagrams.
3. Has the ability to export to HTML programmatically.

This is for documenting a complex protocol.

The closest I've found so far is the excellent [Markdown Preview Enhanced plugin for Atom](https://github.com/shd101wyy/markdown-preview-enhanced). It supports PlantUML, Graphviz, Katex, automatic TOC generation and so on. It's pretty awesome, but unfortunately there is no way to automatically export to HTML - you have to open each file and export it individually. This means that practically, the only way to preview a git repo of Markdown files is to clone it and open it in Atom. Not ideal.

Another close one I've found is [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/editor). It supports sequence diagrams. It doesn't use PlantUML and the diagram syntax isn't nearly as capable (although the default style is a bit nicer). Also the editor is web-based so I'm not sure how I'd use it as an offline editor easily.

Finally, there is [Gitbook](https://www.gitbook.com/). It generates nice HTML from Markdown and there are plenty of PlantUML plugins. There's even a nice offline editor (closed source but I'm not that bothered about that). Unfortunately the offline editor doesn't invoke the plugins, so you don't get a live preview of the sequence diagrams while you are editing them.

Does anyone have any more suggestions?

Comment: What did you end up using? Also, what's your OS?

Comment: I didn't find anything great, and moved jobs so no longer needed it. However VSCode has matured a lot over the last year - might be worth checking out its support for PlantUML and Mermaid. I suspect Mermaid would be easier to generate HTML from.

Answer (score 1):

About the only one that's convincing enough for me to believe is [Typora](https://typora.io/).